# How do I regress income quartiles against each other?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding, controlling-for-a-variable, interquartile

I'm looking to find out whether an attitude differs across income quartiles. My supervisor has mentioned dummy coding and regressing the quartiles against each other, however, I'm sort of at a loss as to how to do this.

Would I just include the variable whereby each respondent is coded into a quartile as a predictor in multiple regression (alongside other demographic controls?) Or would I have to run separate regressions comparing each dummy coded quartile to the lowest reference quartile.

If however, this is the wrong way to go about it, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: "Regressing quartiles against each other" is an odd phrasing. Can you ask your supervisor to clarify? 

Also, if you have actual income data, then I would use that and not quartiles.

Comment: There are different approaches to study the association between two ordinal variables (or one numeric and one ordinal). Quartile "encoding" is a bit exotic. Maybe it is best to ask your supervisor for a statistics reference to this approach.

Comment: *Finding out* means *exploring* and *investigating.*  Consider starting with suitable graphical displays of the distribution of measures of attitude broken down by income quarters.  Boxplots, violin plots, dot plots, and their like come immediately to mind.  Even if your advisor *has* said something like "regress ... quartiles against each other," I seriously doubt that's what they *meant.*